# Проблема с friend в c++

Tags: c++

Вот пишу заголовочный файл:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_SENTRY
#define TEST_H_SENTRY

class ss1;
class ss2;

class ss1{
        int x1;
        void qwer1(ss2*);
public:
        friend void ss2::qwer2(ss1*);
};

class ss2{
        int x2;
        void qwer2(ss1*);
public:
        friend void ss1::qwer1(ss2*);
};

#endif
```

Компилятор пишет:

test.h:11:29: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ss2’
friend void ss2::qwer2(ss1*);

test.h:5:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class ss2’
class ss2;

Не пойму в чем дело и как исправить. Помогите :-)

Comment: Не понятно, зачем вам для публичных методов вдруг такое могло понадобиться?

Comment: ой да. я изменил, но ошибка все равно осталось.

Comment: Да просто добавьте класс как дружественный к другому, и все... `friend class ss1; friend class ss2;`

Comment: Проблема в том, что на момент обработки строки `friend void ss2::qwer2(ss1*);` компилятор ещё не знает, что у `ss2` есть метод  `void qwer2(ss1*);`

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы он об этом узнал?

Comment: Вроде никак. Потому что `ss1` будет требовать полного определения класса `ss2` перед собой, а `ss2` будет требовать полного определения класса `ss1` перед собой.

Comment: @EOF ну тогда ладно. спасибо

Comment: @EOF, предварительное объявление

Comment: @Egorithm Вы о чём? Предварительное объявление чего?

Comment: @EOF, решение этой проблемы - предварительное объявление (forward declaration). Чего? - Классов.

Comment: @Egorithm Вопрос был о том, как сделать дружественными методы. У ТС и так есть предварительные объявления классов в коде вопроса.

Comment: @EOF, да, не заметил. Я с таким не сталкивался. Довольно странных подход. Лучше просто сделать классы друзьями.

Answer (score 2):

Циклическая проблема (курицы и яйца) - А обращается к Б, а потому Б должно быть раньше А, а Б обращается к А, а потому А должно быть раньше Б. Поэтому в рамках поставленной задачи решения нет.

Answer (score 2):

Выборочное разрешение методов двух классов друг другу можно реализовать с помощью базового класса. Этот класс будет содержать только эти функции. И защита будет стандартной. Этим функциям будет разрешён доступ к двум классам. И вызывать эти функции можно только внутри этих классов. Нужно сделать эти функции статическими, для того, чтобы тип объекта соответствовал имени функции.

```
// g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 frinamspa4.hpp
#ifndef TEST_H_SENTRY
#define TEST_H_SENTRY

class ss1 ;
class ss2 ;

class friends {
  // для защиты от создания пустого абстрактного объекта
  friends ( void ) { } 
protected :
  // статический вариант для правильных типов
  static  void qwer2  ( ss2 & , ss1 * ) ;
  static  void qwer1  ( ss1 & , ss2 * ) ;
} ;

class ss1 : protected friends {
  int x1;
  friend friends ;
  void qwer1(ss2*);
public:
  void test(ss2 * s2) {
    qwer2 ( * s2 , this ) ; }
} ;

class ss2 : protected friends {
  int x2;
  friend friends ;
  void qwer2(ss1*);
public:
  void test(ss1 * s1) {
    qwer1 ( * s1 , this ) ; }
} ;

void friends::qwer2  ( ss2 & me , ss1 * const s1 ) {
  me . qwer2 ( s1 ) ; }
    
void friends::qwer1  ( ss1 & me , ss2 * const s2 ) {
  me . qwer1 ( s2 ) ; }
  
#endif
```

Comment: Разрешается ли создание экземпляра класса `friends`?

Comment: Ради бога, всё упадёт. Почитайте про абстрактные классы. Как их сделать. А если использовать статические функции, то он не пригодится. @TigerTV.ru

Comment: Слушайте, я не докапываюсь, я просто спрашиваю. Про абстрактные классы давно читал, там `virtual` используется, у вас такого нет. Если использовать только статические функции, то объект класса все равно можно создать. Рекомендация: сделайте конструктор приватным.

Comment: Хорошо, сделал. @TigerTV.ru

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам нужно что то подобное:

```
class ss2;
class ss1 {
    int x1;
    //определение функции_члена написать после определения ss2
    static void qwer1(ss2*);
public:
    friend class ss2;    
};

class ss2 {
    int x2;
    //ss1 определен, можно написать определение
    static void qwer2(ss1* s) 
    {
        //...
    }
public:
    friend class ss1;   
};
void ss1::qwer1(ss2* s)
{
    //...
}
```

p.s. пока неизвестны точные намерения(для чего эти функции), ответ будет только примерным. Если хотите только функцию_член объявить другом, то класс должен быть уже определен, и функция_член должна быть общедоступным:

```
class ss2;
class ss1 {
    int x1;
public:    
    void qwer1(ss2*){} 
    // friend  void ss2::qwer2(ss1*);
    //это вы не сможете объявить, так как ss2 еще не определен
};

class ss2 {
    int x2;
public: 
    void qwer2(ss1*) {}
    friend  void ss1::qwer1(ss2*); //можно
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я всё же пытался сделать дружественным не весь класс, а лишь одну функцию. И похоже, сделать это не возможно )

Comment: Невозможно, потому что эти функции_члены у вас закрытые. Вот если их сделать публичными, тогда можно

Comment: Здесь проблема не в публичности, а в цикличности ссылок (обращений, а не ссылок в смысле С++).

Comment: @Mikhailo, в ответе   об этом  есть комментарий

Answer (score 1):

А как насчет использования `nested classes`? friend используется только для методов.

```cpp
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST

#include <iostream>

class E {
private:
    E();
public:
    class I;
    class K;

private:
    static void printI(I* i) {
        std::cout << i->y << std::endl;
    }

    static void printK(K* k) {
        std::cout << k->y << std::endl;
    }
public:

    class I {
    private:
        int y;
        friend void E::printI(I* i);
    public:
        I(int x) {this->y = x;}
        void printFriend(K* k) {
            E::printK(k);
        }
    };

    class K {
    private:
        int y;
        friend void E::printK(K* k);
    public:
        K(int x) {this->y = x;}
        void printFriend(I* i) {
            E::printI(i);
        }
    };

};

#endif
```